# How to create an alphabetical section index for a List in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui, swiftui-list

I would like to know how I can filter my list and create an alphabetical section index to the side of a `List` in SwiftUI, as is possible with the `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView` `UITableViewDataSource` delegate method in `UIKit`.

[Here is an example of what I would like to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Id4SC.png)

How can I do this?

Here is the list I have so far: [List built so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uoi76.png)

Comment: Yes I Do, but how would I put the alphabetical list seen on the right graphically

Comment: Using a `UITableView` or a `UICollectionView`. Learning how to construct a view controller with a table view in it should be your starting point, not sorting an array alphanumerically.

Comment: So there is no way of doing it with the List view of swiftUI ??

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you were using SwiftUI. Yes, start with `List`.

Comment: I have but what should I do now to make the alphabetical indexed list ? (See up for the list I made)

Comment: List does not have all the features of UITableView. I don't believe this feature is available.

Comment: That index to the side is called UILocalized​Indexed​Collation. And no, it's not possible to make it in pure SwiftUI yet.

Comment: @bsod you should work on your politeness. OP's original question seems pretty well-formed an relevant to me. Didn't need you to be patronising and snarky. Be kinder please.

Comment: @sam-w zero snark or rudeness intended in my comments—just an economy of words. I’m super nice (see trailing emoji)! 

Comment: @YonatanBensimon were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: @YonatanBensimon were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58809357/swiftui-list-with-section-index-on-right-hand-side

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a similar delegate method in SwiftUI you won't find one. Not yet at least.

I would suggest building a separate VStack of the section indexes (array you built already as you normally would for the delegate). Then just wrap your section indexes and your List in a ZStack.